# Plural verb used after 'type'

Tags: verb-agreement

Today I was reading a programming book and I encountered the following sentence (emphases mine):

> In this case, for example, **the type** that all three compilers report
>   for `param` **are** incorrect.

I'm *not* an English native speaker but since the very first moment I went through that statement I felt like something didn't flow smoothly:

the subject of the sentence (the type) seems to be singular, however the verb that refers to it (are) is plural. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: If the sentence is intended to be "The type [that all three compilers report for param] is/are incorrect, then the head of the subject is the singular "type", and the verb should also be the plural “is”. The bracketed relative clause is simply an optional modifier; dropping it makes things clearer: “the type is incorrect”, where only singular "is" is possible.

Comment: Note also that the antecedent of "that" is "type", which functions as object of "report", thus "all three compilers report the type for param is incorrect". Plural "are" is simply not possible at all, so I can't see what Oliver is getting at.

Comment: @BillJ It is a bit of a laboured interpretation, admittedly, but the point is that while each compiler only reports one type, the result of three compilers reporting a type each is a set of three types, so the 'logical' subject of _are_ could be a plural, even though grammatically it is expressed in the singular (as it applies to each compiler separately).

Comment: But we cannot get around the fact that the head of the NP subject is the singular "type", and it's this that determines the verb for number agreement purposes. Also, I believe that the original author of this particular sentence used "is".

Comment: This is a good place for a reduced passive relative: _The types reported  for `param`by all three compilers are incorrect._

Comment: @JohnLawler that's exactly what I initially thought of.
Is that how I should interpret the statement in my question?

Comment: @BillJ I believe it's Scott Meyer's "Effective C++", and it indeed uses _are_; so the quote by the OP is correct. The following sentence is "Furthermore, they're essentially required to be incorrect [...]",  so continues with a plural reference.

Comment: The information that all 3 reports are wrong is all that's necessary since it's irrelevant whether the 3 reports were different, as long as they're all wrong.

Comment: @OliverMason The original quote that I saw uses "is". See here [link](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html). You'll find it about 75% of the way through where he says: _Sadly, the results of std::type_info::name are not reliable. In this case, for example, the type that all three compilers report for param **is** incorrect. Furthermore ..._

Comment: @brainplot Writing it another way is irrelevant. The original quote that I saw uses **is**. See the link I just gave to Oliver.

Comment: @BillJ I have seen a different version with _are_; so it might be a version difference. But how do you then explain the use of _they're_ in the following sentence?

Comment: I just checked and my book says _are_, which is weird because there seems to be only one version of this book available.

Comment: I would trust the version from the link that @BillJ posted, at this point. Maybe what we're discussing about on here was already reported to the author/publisher and they only updated the "web version". Printed copies will reflect the changes with future versions I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different interpretations:

1. All three compilers report the same type, which is incorrect. In that case it should be singular *is*.
2. Each compiler reports a different type. So all three types are not correct, but they are not the same either. In that case *are* is fine.

While each compiler only reports a single type, there are three of them, and so the resulting list of types might contain several different ones or just one and the same.

UPDATE: The text (Scott Meyers' *Effective C++*) continues with the sentence *Furthermore, they're essentially required to be incorrect [...]*, so with a plural reference. This indicates to me that the author indeed means to refer to the three types; but uses the singular *type* as each compiler only reports one. It is an interesting usage, though *types* would probably have been less confusing in this instance.

Comment: The three compilers described in the book effectively report the same type but one of them uses a different notation. Does that mean that "are" is fine?

Comment: @brainplot Depends; different to tell without knowing the exact notation. I would guess the author regards them as different, then _are_ would make sense. Otherwise it should be _is_. But it's impossible to know the author's reasoning!

Comment: thank you! I'm going to just upvote this question for now. I will gladly accept it in case no one else shows up :)

Comment: Accepted. I too find it to be an interesting usage.
P.S. The author's last name is _Meyers_ (note the final 's') :)

Comment: @brainplot Thanks -- I missed that. Corrected it in the answer.